# Vuetify - Why v-menu with open-on-hover is closing when mouse is over a list of v-select or v-combobox components

Tags: vue-component, vuetify.js, preventdefault, event-propagation, v-select

steps to reproduce:

1 - place a v-menu with open-on-hover property
2 - add a v-select or a v-combobox item to it..

when v-menu is opened,  and the lists from v-select or v-combobox are displayed,
v-menu automatically closes if mouse hovers the list.  (note, only when hovering the LIST that vcombobox or v-select opens)

Tried to prevent with event.stopPropagation();  and no success.